# How to generate set of enumerations with even number of ones

Tags: c++, macros, enumeration

I have an idea of how to prevent a single bit flip (due to cosmic radiation or similar externally induced event) from causing enumerations (enum) to change from one defined value to another defined value in a relatively easy way. To put it simple each value should have an even amount of ones, binary speaking. If one flips, the enum will be odd and is guaranteed not to match any other enum.

I'm not sure how to actually "generate" such a sequence so that it may be used as enum values as those values must be compile time constant. A macro function returning the n:th element in the set would do perfectly.

The first few numbers in the sequence would be 0 (000), 3 (011), 5 (101), 6 (110). I think you get the idea by now.

Non-enumeration (non-compile time) answers are appreciated as it may help me realize how to do it myself.

---

To make myself clear I want a macro generating the n:th number in an enum with even number of ones in the bit pattern, similar to macros generating the fibbonachi sequence. The lowest bit is essentially a parity bit.

---

Most of my memory is protected by hardware ECC, L1 cache being one exception. A single bit error in L1 has been measured to occur once every 10000h which is good enough seen from my requirements.

VRAM however is not protected. There I have mostly RGB(A) raster, a few general purpose raster (like stencil) and some geometry. RGB raster is rather unsensative to bit flips as it is only used for visualization. Erroneous geometry is in general very visible, very rare (few KB) and is by design to be resolved by user induced reboot.

For a 4096x4096x8bit stencil (~16MB) single bit error rate is in my environment about once every 8h for average cosmic radiation, more often during solar storms. It is actually not that bad in my opinion, but I'd hate filling the paper work proving to my officers why this is perfectly fine in my application and everyone elses using the stencil data without regard to how the data is used. If having a parity bit in the stencil value however I'd be able to detect most errors and if necessary re-generate the stencil hoping for better results. The stencil can be generated in less than a second so the risk of errors occuring twice in a row is considered low.

So basically, by generating a set of enumerations with parity I dodge the bullet of current and future paper work and research regarding how it may affect my app and others'.

Comment: and what if two bits get flipped?  we're not here to design your system/code for you. We fix what YOU've written. anything else is simply us doing your job for you.

Comment: Think combinations: all possible 2 bits set out of say 16; then all possible 4 bits set out of 16; 6/16; 8/16 etc.

Comment: I don't much see the point in this method because it doesn't provide a mechanism for restoring an enum after a bit has been flipped; if you see `001` its ambiguous whether it should be `0`, `3`, or `5`

Comment: What if the cosmic rays also flip bits in the code segment and change `==` into `!=`?

Comment: @RichardCritten I thought of that and did not find an easy way to express it as a macro.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Restoration can be made by reloading the value from some other place or rebooting the system.

Comment: This proposed macro: is it supposed to work on any expression, or only on a constant? And on what range of values?

Comment: @rici Constant only will suffice, although using previous enum entry would also do just fine as proposed by Richard Hodges. 0-127 fitting in 8-bit will do for my application. I guess my range kind of changes the prerequisites as overflow considerations may be omitted. Good point.

Comment: If you only need to detect single-bit errors, and if you don't need to convert back to an ordinal, you could use [Gray codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#Converting_to_and_from_Gray_code). Since every Gray code differs from the previous one by exactly one bit, the codes alternate in parity and so if you use every second Gray code, single-bit errors will always be detectable, Gray(k) is `(k^(k>>1))`, but to get every second one you'd need Gray(2k) which is `((k<<1)^k))`.  This is the opposite of parity: parity(k) is complicated, unparity(k) while is easy.

Comment: ...On the other hand, if you're only doing constant values in a fixed range, you could compute the k'th number of even parity (parity(k)) using a long expression which still produces a compile-time constant: `(k<<1)^(1&(k^(k>>1)^(k>>2)^(k>>3)^(k>>4)^(k>>5)^(k>>6)))`.

Comment: Also, you might want to read about Reed-Solomon encodings (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction), which can be computed efficiently.

Comment: @rici Enums require values to be strictly ascending. Every second Gray code would not work. Still it is very useful. I'm considering to drop the enum constraint in favor of this method (using set of integer constants).

Comment: I don't believe C99 imposes any ordering requirement on enum members.

Comment: @rici You are right. I mixed it up with some other tools and languages at my disposal.

Comment: In case this question is never reopened I put my solution here. I go with the excellent solution proposed by @rici to use (every second) [Gray Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#Converting_to_and_from_Gray_code). For even k in Gray(k) a number with even number of set bits is generated. Gray(2k) is hidden in the parity num gen. Code is: `#define PARITY_NUM(k) (((k)<<1)^(k))` whereas usage is `enum foo {bar=PARITY_NUM(0), baz=PARITY_NUM(1)};`

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to know if the enum is either valid or if a bit is flipped, you can use any values and a parity bit that makes the total number of bits even. (which this first sequence is identical to your example)

```
0000000 0 = 0
0000001 1 = 3
0000010 1 = 5
0000011 0 = 6
0000100 1 = 9
0000101 0 = 10
0000110 0 = 12
0000111 1 = 15
```

which can be done by

```
int encode_enum(int e) {
    return (e << 1) + (number_of_bits_set(e) % 2);
}
```

However, if you want to be able to restore the value, then a simple way is duplication; have multiple copies of the value that can be later compared to eachother. You'd need 3 copies to restore it. If your list of values is small, you can encode it into one integer.

```
int encode_enum(int e) {
    return (e << 20) | (e << 10) | e;
}
```

Which if `e` is less than `2^10` is just copied 3 times into a single 32-bit integer.

Comment: You have an interesting point on possible restoration by simply having duplicates in the value. While not part of the question it is much appreciated information.

Answer (score 1):

c++14's `constexpr` solves this for you:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr int bit_count(int val)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 31 ; ++i) {
        if (val & (1 << i))
            ++count;
    }
    return count;
}

constexpr int next_bitset(int last)
{
    int candidate = last + 1;
    if (bit_count(candidate) & 1)
        return next_bitset(candidate);
    return candidate;
}
enum values
{
    a,
    b = next_bitset(a),
    c = next_bitset(b),
    d = next_bitset(c)
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b = " << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c = " << c << std::endl;
    std::cout << "d = " << d << std::endl;
}
```

expected output:

```
a = 0
b = 3
c = 5
d = 6
```

Comment: I'm stuck with C99 a couple of years more but this will be useful to me when the time is right and for others with up to date environments.

Comment: @andreas shame. What kind of organisation deliberately lives in the dark ages? I think your concern about stray space particles is a little overdone though. It takes more than one stray muon to flip a bit. If it's a real concern then a CRC or some more complex hash will give you better protection than parity alone.

Comment: Military organizations. Old tech is much more robust and have better service records. We have made the conclusions based on measurements in labs showering the equipment with particles according to certification standards as applicable to our product. CRC captures errors in code, not user data. Hashing 16million runtime generated elements in less than a second (on old tech) is just not feasible.

Comment: @Andreas fair enough I guess. The claim that an old compiler is more reliable than a new one is interesting. I'd be interested to see the data supporting that. I don't agree with you on CRC not being able to protect data - it's the core of error detection in IP4 - which is a protocol designed to withstand all out nuclear war. Let's hope your low-tech robot doesn't meet a high-tech Chinese one on the battlefield ;-)

Comment: @RichardHodges: http://www.evanjones.ca/tcp-and-ethernet-checksums-fail.html

Comment: @rici interesting, but the cause of the problem was an incorrect implementation of a CRC calculation in a router, not an inherent unreliability in CRC itself.

Comment: @RichardHodges: That's true; it's simply an example of failed error detection. (If solar radiation flips a bit inside a router, and the router recomputes the CRC based on the flipped data, then the CRC doesn't help.) But note that he's talking about 4-byte Ethernet CRC, not 2-byte TCP CRC; look at his older article for the issue with the 2-byte CRC. (http://www.evanjones.ca/tcp-checksums.html).

Comment: @RichardHodges Ok, I suspect a minor misunderstanding of CRC from my side. I only have experience with services provided by our equipment sub-contractors where CRC check internal state consistency by continuosly evaluating a fixed function, constant input result against a fixed data reference, not data which I provide/generate.